# Bundler error when trying to deploy with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano, bundler

I am trying to deploy to a remote VPS via Capistrano 3. The VPS tuns on Ubuntu 12.04, Apache, and rvm. When I use `cap production deploy` on my local computer, it begins to deploy, but then throws a bundler error and quits:

`An error occurred while installing minitest (4.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.`

See here for documentation: https://gist.github.com/atkolkma/9551199

`gem install minitest -v 4.7.5`
Executes successfully. But if I run
`gem -v minitest` 
It says I have version 2.2.2 ! This happens on BOTH machines. Could it be rvm that is doing this? A bundler issue? I have no idea.

UPDATE: I installed RVM, Ruby and Rails as root on the VPS. I am pretty sure this was causing permissions or path problems for Capistrano when trying to bundle my project. I will try to rebuild the VPS with a deployer or rails user. I'll update when I solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you installing `minitest` on production environment?

Comment: I am not trying to. It's just an error that Bundler is throwing at me on deploy. Not sure why it is even looking for minitest.

Comment: Add `minitest` under the `group :test, :development` in your Gemfile. `group :test, :development do gem 'minitest' end`

Comment: updated the Gemfile. It STILL throws the error that it can't install minitest

Comment: I just removed .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset and the error went away. However, not I get the error `Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile. ( see: 'rvm usage' )` Am I just creating these files wrong?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I installed RVM, Ruby and Rails as root on the VPS. I am pretty sure this was causing permissions or path problems for Capistrano when trying to bundle my project. I will try to rebuild the VPS with a deployer or rails user. I'll update when I solve this problem.